# want to form an array by jquery to post that array

Tags: html, jquery

I want to form an array by using for  loop for posting that array value containing 12 months value.
I am using some code as below:

```
 $('#savebudget').live('click', function () {
            var obj = {
                for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
                    var bud=$('#bud_'+i).attr("value"),
                    'm'.i:bud;
                }
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: obj,
                url:root+'team/sales?json',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Budget Saved Successfully");
                },
                datatype: 'json'
            });
```

where I want to post "obj" with ajax containing the budget values of 12 months .
I  have tried it also as below:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
                        var bud=$('#bud_'+i).attr("value"),
                        'm'+i:bud;
                    }
```

can anybody tell me that how can I make the "obj"??

Comment: Don't use `live`, it is deprecated and will be removed in the future; it also has terrible performance. You could replace it with a `delegate` but in this case you probably should just use a normal `click` handler since you are addressing it via `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.map` and `.join` jQuery method that will help.

```
var passStr = $('input[id^="#bud_"]').map(function()
{
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");
```

and then send it to `$.ajax` .

Remember above will not create `Object` it will create string and also replace `.live()` with `.on()` because `.live()` is deprecated from new version.

Comment: for (i=1;i<13;i++)
{
var passStr = $('input[id^="#bud_"]').map(function()
{
    return $(this).val();
}).get().join(",");
}

can I used it as like this code?

Comment: @Rahul_RJ nope you can't use it..BTW are you rahul prajapati from VGEC.?

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {};

$('input').each(function (i) {
    var key = 'm' + i;
    data[key] = this.value;
});
```

Comment: I want to post it as m1,m2,m3....m12  

& I want to post these by using these in data used for posting values via  ajax